# Javascript "Classes": child method as sub class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, module, prototype

In the example below, if i have in `Child1` *Class* a method `SubClass` treated as a *Class* to, how to get `Child1` reference in `SubClass`?

```js
// parents
function Parent1() {
  this.parent = 'Parent1';
}

function Parent2() {
  this.parent = 'Parent2';
}

// child
function Child1() {
  Parent1.call(this);
  this.child = 'Child1';
}
Child1.prototype = Object.create(Parent1.prototype);

// child method as sub class
Child1.prototype.SubClass1 = function(){
  Parent2.call(this);
  this.sub_class = 'SubClass1';
};
Child1.prototype.SubClass1.prototype = Object.create(Parent2.prototype);

Child1.prototype.SubClass1.prototype.whoami = function(){
    // how to get Child1 reference in this point?
    console.log({
        parent: this.parent,
        child: this.child, // undefined
        sub_class: this.sub_class
    });
};

var child = new Child1;
var sub = new child.SubClass1;

sub.whoami();
```

Comment: simply using this?

Comment: @Jonasw, but `this.child` returns `undefined`, how could it returns `Child1`?

Comment: Your code is very very messy. Use module pattern if you want to package constructors and isolate them...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would to not use the new constructor:

```
Child1.prototype.SubClass1 = function(){
  var obj=Object.create(this.SubClass1_proto);
   obj.sub_class = 'SubClass1';
  return obj;
};


Child1.prototype.SubClass1_proto=Object.create(new Parent2());
Child1.prototype.SubClass1_proto.whoami = function(){
// how to get Child1 reference in this point?
console.log({
    parent: this.parent,
    child: this.child, // undefined
    sub_class: this.sub_class
  });
};
```

Use like this

```
instance=new Child1();
Sub=instance.SubClass1();
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonasw. I've tried your solution, but `this.child` always return `undefined`. I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramabarca/ujgkw5u7/) with your solution. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dq8mfjoq/ now the problem is that this doesnt return to the object, but to window...

Comment: @ramabarca could you specify why you need this? ( give a small description of what youve tried to achieve?)